# UITabBarController hide More navigationbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

When there are 5 or more `viewcontrollers` for a `UITabBarController`, by default, the More option will be available.

When you select those 'more' `viewcontrollers`, the `viewcontroller` presented will have a Navigation Bar and a back button.

Is there a way to hide this navigation bar?

Comment: Oh just figured it out. :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Modified the code below
for the `UITabBarController`, set:

```
[self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
```